# NavigationExperimental property `onNavigateBack` not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a `react-native` project and upgraded from `0.26` to `0.30` recently. **NavigationExperimental** received a fair amount of changes, particularly on naming (`NavigationRoute`, `NavigationState`, …) and a change on the method `onNavigate` for `NavigationCardStack` which becomes `onNavigateBack`.

I'm using **flow** `0.27.0` to check my code.

So here's the error I get from **flow**.

```
app/containers/MyContainer.js:99
 99:            <NavigationCardStack
                ^ props of React element `NavigationCardStack`
 67: type Props = NavigationSceneRendererProps & {
                                                 ^ property `onNavigateBack`. Property not found in. See: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationHeader.js:67
113:                {...props}
                        ^^^^^ spread of identifier `props`

app/containers/MyContainer.js:112
112:            <NavigationHeader
                ^ React element `NavigationHeader`
 67: type Props = NavigationSceneRendererProps & {
                                                 ^ property `onNavigateBack`. Property not found in. See: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationHeader.js:67
113:                {...props}
                        ^^^^^ spread of identifier `props`
```

And here is the code where the error occurs. `this.props.onNavigateBack` gets its value from redux's `connect` method.

```
class MyContainer extends Component {
    props: Props;

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationCardStack
                navigationState={this.props.navigationState}
                onNavigateBack={this.props.onNavigateBack}
                renderOverlay={props => this._renderNavigationHeader(props)}
                renderScene={scene => (<View />)}
                style={styles.container}
            />
        )
    }

    _renderNavigationHeader(props) {
        return (
            <NavigationHeader
                {...props}
                style={styles.header}
                textStyle={styles.title}
                renderLeftComponent={props => (<View />)}
                renderRightComponent={props => (<View />)}
                renderTitleComponent={props => (<View />)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

I tried to make the code as short as possible, note `Props` type I declared contains `onNavigateBack` as a `() => void`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understood. I assumed `renderOverlay` passed `onNavigateBack` to the method it's given but seems it's not the case. Not sure about it but I think it was the case before when it was still `onNavigate`.

So the fix is to directly refer to `this.props.onNavigateBack` instead of looking inside `props` through spread operator.

```
_renderNavigationHeader(props) {
    return (
        <NavigationHeader
            {…props}
            onNavigateBack={this.props.onNavigateBack}
            style={styles.header}
            textStyle={styles.title}
            renderLeftComponent={props => (<View />)}
            renderRightComponent={props => (<View />)}
            renderTitleComponent={props => (<View />)}
        />
    )
}
```